# Kubernetes1.9.0 kubeadm init - crictl not found in system path

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am setting up kubernetes cluster on a Centos 7 machine, and the `kubeadm init` command gives me the below warning message.

```
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.9.0
[init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
        [WARNING SystemVerification]: docker version is greater than the most recently validated version. Docker version: 17.09.1-ce. Max validated version: 17.03
        [WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
```

How can I fix this `crictl not found in system path` warning? Do I need to install any additional software?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need additional software. crictl is part of the [cri-tools](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-tools/releases) repo on github.

At least when I encountered this problem (Dec 20, 2017), cri-tools isn't available on kubernete's package repo, so I had to download source and build it. cri-tools is written in go, so you may need to install golang on your system as well.

Answer (score 3):

I installed crictl with

```
   go get github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-tools/cmd/crictl
```

If you don have go on your system, you could install crictl from

https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-tools/releases